# C#, Android: Create bitmap with single color

Tags: c#, android

I want to create a bitmap that is filled with only one color (#eeeeee). 
I managed to create a bitmap and set it to its viewholder but I cannot seem to find the right way to fill it entierely with my desired color. The output is always only a white rectangle. But it needs to be greyish as in #eeeeee. This is my effort:

```
            Bitmap greyBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(1000, 500, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
            Bitmap mutableBitmap = greyBitmap.Copy(Bitmap.Config.Argb8888, true);//&lt;–true makes copy mutable
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.Color = new Color(Color.ParseColor("#eeeeee"));
            canvas.DrawRect(1000, 500, 1000, 500, paint);
            vh.dr = new BitmapDrawable(mutableBitmap);
```

Chances are, I am taking too many steps... Feel free to correct me on this.

Comment: The coordinates you have in `DrawRect()` are off. The first two should be `0, 0`. Anyway, there's a much simpler way to do that. Just call `eraseColor()` with your color value on the mutable `Bitmap`.

Comment: oh yesm thanks that did the trick. however, would you mind posting both remarks as an answer that i could accept? thank you!

Comment: Oh, I'm good. Just a couple simple suggestions. :-) Please feel free to post your own answer. This would be a handy duplicate target in the future for users asking specifically for C# code. Btw, I just double checked, and that particular `Bitmap.CreateBitmap()` overload returns a mutable `Bitmap` already, so there's no need to copy it first. You can do the whole thing in two lines. Anyhoo, thanks for the offer. I appreciate it. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: your wish shall be my command ;)

Answer (score 0):

With the fantastic help of Mike M.

```
        Bitmap greyBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(1000, 500, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(greyBitmap );
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.Color = new Color(Color.ParseColor("#eeeeee")); // set any color here 
        canvas.DrawRect(0, 0, 1000, 500, paint);
        vh.dr = new BitmapDrawable(greyBitmap );
```